# Ricci tensor of direct products of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Imagine I have a (Lorentzian) manifold with a metric

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   g_{\mu\nu} &0\\
   0&g_{mn}\\
   \end{array} } \right]$

Will the Ricci tensor be also block diagonal without any mixing of the two manifolds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct. As observed already by Ficken in 1939, Ricci tensor is decomposable from which your "also block diagonal without any mixing of the two manifolds" follows. Note however that not all curvature tensors are decomposable (e.g. Weyl tensor is not decomposable).